# How to store Component Factory for dynamic component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a "static" component that has the task to render many dynamic components. These dynamic components need different factories (but reusable) because they have different html templates. 
I tried to store in session storage all types of factories with:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(this.keyStorage, JSON.stringify(compFactory));
```

compFactory is then used without problem and it creates all my dynamic components.

The problem is when I refresh my app and I try to get the item from the storage:

```
const myFactory = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.keyStorage));
```

myFactory is in the sessionStorage and seems to be right, but when I tried to create the component, an error in console appears: "createComponent is not a function"

Thank you if you can explain why this happens.

Comment: You can't stringify a component factory.

Comment: So I have to store the factories in a variable. Thank you